# R ggplot2 Increase Number of Gridlines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to increase the number of gridlines on my plot (`ggplot2`). However as my plotting pipeline is automated I do not know the scales of the axis.

How I can increase the number of gridlines without knowing the scale (I can't use the standard method of listing the positions were gridlines will be because I don't know this in advance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot has a built in `pretty_breaks` function for this purpose:

> scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=10))

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy function in base R, called `pretty()`, that computes 
pretty sequences:

```
set.seed(1)
pretty(rnorm(10), n=5)
#[1] -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0
pretty(rnorm(10), n=10)
# [1] -2.5 -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0
```

The argument `n` determines the number of breaks. You can use this within ggplot2:

```
dd = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(dd$x, n=20), 
                     limit=range(pretty(dd$x, n=20)))
```